# Kotlin expect actual datatypes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Is it possible to define an expectation for a datatype in commonMain and then provide the actual datatype in jvmMain or jsMain?

for example lets say I wanted to use the local datatypes for Date in both JavaScript and Java in a commonMain class:

```
// commonMain
expect datatype Date

// jsMain
actual datatype Date = Date()

// jvmMain
actual datatype Date = LocalDate()
```

is such a thing possible? if so what does the syntax look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are basically classes. So here is the syntax

```
//commonMain [Date.kt]
expect class Date

//jsMain [Date.kt]
actual typealias Date = kotlin.js.Date //this one implements the js date

//jvmMain [Date.kt]
actual typealias Date = java.util.Date //or you can use the java.time.LocalDateTime
```

hope this helps